# Not choosing existing selection when randomising

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a speech bubble that displays quotes that I store in lists. When I click the bubble it picks another quote from the list at random, but sometimes chooses the one it is already displaying. How would I prevent it from doing this?

```
<ul class="joke-list">
    <li id="quotes">
        <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span style="font-size: medium;">Charles Darwin wanted to be a doctor but did not like the sight of blood.</span></span></li>
    <li id="quotes">
        <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span style="font-size: medium;">Charles Darwin was a member of the Gourmet Club. He ate lots of animals including armadillos, owls and tigers.</span></span></li>
    <li id="quotes">
        <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span style="font-size: medium;">For his 25th Birthday, Charles Darwin had a mountain named after him in Zimbabwe. </span></span></li>
</ul>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FsjkM/236/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it

```
$.fn.extend({

   rnditem : function(l) {
        var current = $(this).text(),
            next = (l.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * l.length)).text());

       while (next === current) {
           next = (l.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * l.length)).text());
       }

$(this).text(next);

      return this;
   }
 });

$(document).ready(function () {

   var list = $(".joke-list").find("#quotes");

$(document.body).on('click','.speech', function () {

$(this).rnditem(list);
   });

$(".speech").trigger("click");

});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/FsjkM/237/)

In answer to your additional question below, a solution would be

```
$.fn.extend({
   rnditem : function(l) {
        var a = [],
            current = $(this).text().trim(),
            index,
            next;

       Array.prototype.forEach.call(l, function(item) {
            a.push($(item).text().trim());
       });

       index = a.indexOf(current) + 1;
       if (index < 0 ||  index >= l.length) {
           index = 0;
       }

       next = (l.eq(index).text());

       $(this).text(next);

      return this;
   }
 });
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/FsjkM/240/)

Comment: Thats great thanks. How would I do it so that it picked the next in the list? @Xotic750

Comment: One more thing. The </br> are now displayed as well how would I get around this? @Xotic750

Comment: Change ´text´ to ´html´ throughout the code, but I don't see any BR in the jsfiddle demo

Comment: I mean for the random one @Xotic750

Comment: I see no BR there either, but the same applies, change ´text´ to ´html´ if your quotes now contain HTML

Comment: If you look at this version it does though http://jsfiddle.net/FsjkM/241/. I have tried to hide the </br> trough the css but have had no joy @Xotic750

Comment: Because I need to separate two sections of text. For example "how many legs does a spider have? </br> 8" @Xotic750

Comment: Well, that will cause quite a large refactoring of all your code.